My system wont boot
My system wouldn't boot until I followed a guide so now it boots up to show the different profiles (like it normally would) but when I click on the profile that I want to use and put in the password, it goes to a black screen then it just goes back to the profile selection

Sounds like it might be stuck in a login loop. My initial thought is trying this - from the login screen, press ctrl + alt +f3 to enter grub mode and enter the following commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a

